# Marigold is dying? Recent transplant

Tags: plant-health, transplanting, repotting, drainage

I very recently bought two Marigold plants and transplanted them into a large ceramic pot with no drainage plug. Its a really large basin, I put potting mix and soil. Made sure I watered prior to planting and its looks like it dying. The leaves have a seaweed texture and after I read that they need drainage I stopped watering too much. I have also a lavender plant with the marigolds that looks healthy. Will it be okay if I plucked it out and replanted again in a new pot? The one plant has blooms that haven't bloomed yet but the main flower head wilted in a day. I don't want to shock it too much. HELP!

Comment: What part of the world are you in, and what type of marigold are they (tagetes, Calendula?) When you say recent transplant, does that mean you dug them up from elsewhere, or recently bought them? otherwise, please add a photo